# ComboBox in the header of a DataGridColumn - how to differentiate between columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `ComboBox` in a header of a `DataGrid` column. I want to handle the `SelectionChanged` event of the `ComboBox` but I need to know which control (in header of which column) generated that event. The controls are put in the headers through static resource `DataTemplate` assigned to `HeaderTemplate` in a call to column constructor.

I wanted to use the column data context to set some identifying data on the `ComboBox` but I can't access that context. I could easily access the `DataGrid` data model context but it is the same data for all `ComboBoxes` (columns).

Any idea how can I resolve which column header `ComboBox` generated the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"which column header ComboBox generated the event?"
`(ComboBox)sender` is your handle to the ComboBox that generated the event.

If you need to access the header, or the column containing that ComboBox, you can use the VisualTreeHelper, as discussed here: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)

Based on the information in your question, this answer from that thread might be what you are looking for (by John Myczek) - sub out `Window` for the type you want:

> You can use the VisualTreeHelper to find controls. Below is a method
>   that uses the VisualTreeHelper to find a parent control of a specified
>   type. You can use the VisualTreeHelper to find controls in other ways
>   as well.
>
> ```
> public static class UIHelper
> {
>    /// <summary>
>    /// Finds a parent of a given item on the visual tree.
>    /// </summary>
>    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
>    /// <param name="child">A direct or indirect child of the queried item.</param>
>    /// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
>    /// If not matching item can be found, a null reference is being returned.</returns>
>    public static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
>      where T : DependencyObject
>    {
>       // get parent item
>       DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
>
>       // we’ve reached the end of the tree
>       if (parentObject == null) return null;
>
>       // check if the parent matches the type we’re looking for
>       T parent = parentObject as T;
>       if (parent != null)
>       {
>          return parent;
>       }
>       else
>       {
>          // use recursion to proceed with next level
>          return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Call it like this:
>
> ```
> Window owner = UIHelper.FindVisualParent<Window>(myControl);
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I didn't think about walking up the visual tree... I so wanted to get the reference to the column in the event handler that I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Now I can find the header (instead of the column) and I can use the information from the header's tag property to process the event.